# Check if HTML 5 video element is getting frame

Tags: jquery, html, c++, webrtc, nvidia

I'm using webrtc server which stream video in html 5 video element.
In webrtc server, I'm using NVFBCHWEncoder to grab frames.
In browser, a webrtc peerconnection is created between client and server and the video is automatically played in html 5 video element.
After sometime, the stream get into a not responding state.
I manually send a signal to server to reinitialize the NVFBCHWEncoder instance. After this, the stream continues.

Now I need to detect that whether the video element is getting frame or not so that I can signal the server.

Is there anything similar to this

```
<video id="remote-video" width="1024" height="768" autoplay="" src="blob:[baseUrl]/29ee165c-8900-4053-a12f-20c892fcf76b" >
</video>
<script>
    $("#remote-video").on("frame", function(){
        //my stuff
    });
</script>
```

I've searched about all the properties of HTML 5 video element but could not find anything helpful.

I'm testing all this on firefox.

Moreover, any suggestion regarding NVFBCHWEncoder will be appreciated.

Comment: Why would this be tagged C++?

Comment: Because the server side is in c++ and there might be some suggestions about webrtc or NVFBCHWEncoder.

Answer (score 1):

There is a prefixed (read: non-spec, might go away) property mozPaintedFrames on the video element. Similary, Chrome has webkitDecodedFrameCount.

In addition to that, if the video resize event is called you can infer that a keyframe was received and decoded at least once but that might be less useful to detect freezing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It helped me. But it'll be useful for me if and only if I found these properties on all browsers like opera, safari and edge. Can you please help more?

Answer (score 0):

There are no any callback like that.

Anyway, you can achieve what you want using WebRTC stats reporting.
You can monitor the number of bites or packets received. And if it’s 0 then something wrong with the connection so you can now signalize your backend.

You can get some examples and code on how to use stats api from official webrtc demos https://webrtc.github.io/samples/